# conectar a virtual box mediante RDP

Tags: virtualbox

Buenas a todos, el problema que tengo es virtual box, en el tengo instalado Windows Server 2008.

-He configurado virtual box para aceptar conexiones remotas, ya saben la opción de Pantalla Remota en el puerto 5050. 
-he deshabilitado mi firewall del host (Windows 10)
-Virtual tiene instalado el extension pack

Cuando me quiero conectar desde mi host a mi virtual host mediante RDP poniendo (127.0.0.1:localhost) SOLO SE CONECTA si el metodo de autenticacion es "NULL" en cambio si pongo metodo de autenticacion: "Externo" entonces da error (no especifico sino el error generico de que me contacte con el admin) y no hay forma de hacerlo andar, hoy estuve todo el día en eso e investigando en internet y demas. 
Windows Server 2008 tiene el servidor de remote desktop services activo con licencias CAL instaladas.. tenia un controlador de dominio y active directory y se lo saque para ver si no era eso lo que impedía que me conectara con credenciales y sigue igual (ahora tengo q volver a configurar active directory pfff) ASIQUE NOSE, para mi es el bendito Virtual Box. 
A alguien le ha pasado? alguna ayuda? gracias

Comment: hay una respuesta muy parecida a lo que preguntas en http://superuser.com/questions/954395/unable-to-connect-to-windows-10-vm-using-remote-desktop, revisa si eso te sirve

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta. Entre a "Super User" y si bien tu link no contenia lo que buscaba, si lo encontre en otro de la misma pagina:

http://superuser.com/questions/346002/virtualbox-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-virtualbox-with-windows-server-20?rq=1&newreg=d886329aed6e44c48739da3f07ea913e

Gracias